# How to define a regex that matches 4, 3 or 2 word with that hierarchic order?

Tags: regex, string, perl, text, text-parsing

To be more precise, I need a regex to match 3, 2 or 1 consecutive uppercase words and a number of 2 to 5 digits... and save each word and number in a capturing group... For example:

```
BULDING ROBERT SMITH 362 ---> Should be matched and the following should 
                              be valid: $1="BULDING"; $2="ROBERT"; $3="SMITH"; $4="362";

BULDING STEVENSON 7255 ---> Should be matched and the following should 
                              be valid: $1="BULDING"; $2="STEVENSON"; $3="7255";

BULDING 15 ---> Should be matched and the following should 
                              be valid: $1="BULDING"; $2="15";
```

Until now I came up with following

```
([A-Z]+ )?([A-Z]+ )?([A-Z]+) \b(\d{2,5})\b
```

but doesn't satisfy my needs since it matches also the " " that are immediately after the first and second optional matches... Can you help get it?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a regex for this? It looks an awful lot like a job for `split`

Comment: Well I have simplified the question for explanation propose but since I'm parcing large text strings I think this is the correct way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't capture the space. Use non-capturing groups for the optional:

```
(?:([A-Z]+) )?(?:([A-Z]+) )?([A-Z]+) \b(\d{2,5})\b
```

`(?:...)` creates a non-capturing group, which is a group for the purposes of bracketing up expressions, but does't create a group in the match result.

Comment: Oooh now I understand how it is used... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Just do it in two steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/\b((?:[A-Z]+\s+){1,3})\b(\d+)\b/) {
        my @words = split ' ', $1;
        my $num = $2;

        say "Words = " . join ', ', @words;
        say "Num   = $num";
    }
}

__DATA__
BULDING ROBERT SMITH 362
BULDING STEVENSON 7255
BULDING 15
```

Outputs:

```
Words = BULDING, ROBERT, SMITH
Num   = 362
Words = BULDING, STEVENSON
Num   = 7255
Words = BULDING
Num   = 15
```

Comment: Interesting alternative approach but the previous answer does get it with only one regex as asked so I'm selecting his answer as the correct one... Thanks for answering :)

Comment: You could even not bother with the regex if you know the structure of the data, and just split on space, with the last element being the number.

`my (@words, $num) = split(' ', $line);`

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Small bug in your code: The array on the LHS will consume all the elements from the split, leaving $num as undef.

Comment: @Miller good spot, should've known better than to post untested code! Looks like there isn't a way to write it cleanly in one statement as I'd hoped. The best I came up with is `my ($tail, @head) = (pop @list, @list);`, but that's kind of confusing. Or `my ($tail, @head) = ($list[-1], @list[0..$#list-1]);` :-(

Answer (score 0):

ans：

```
 ([A-Z]+) ([A-Z]+)? ([A-Z]+)? (\d{2,5})
```

This regular express can satify。

I thought you can use `split()` function instead;

```
use strict;
use 5.010;
my $str="BULDING ROBERT SMITH 362";
my @array = split(" ",$str);
my $num = pop(@array);
my ($str1,$str2,$str3) = @array;
say $str1;
say $str2 if $str2;
say $str3 if $str3;
```

Comment: Thanks but the program requires later use of matched groups that's why a regex was asked. Also, long strings will be parsed... Lots of junk elements would be added to the array in such implementation